# Getting wrong indices for items in a list using a for loop

Tags: list, indexing

I was trying to return the indices of two element in a list whose sum would be equal to the target value(leetcode problem):

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in nums :
        for j in nums:
            if nums.index(i)!=nums.index(j) and i+j==target:
                return nums.index(i),nums.index(j)
```

```
Your input:
    [2,7,11,15]

    9

Output:
    [0,1]
Expected:
    [0,1]
```

for the given input the above snippet is working fine but for [3,3] it returns "[]"

```
Input:
    [3,3]
    6
Output:
    []
Expected:
    [0,1]
```

i've tried to use simple for loops ,not only for [3,3] for all same inputs it is returning []
eg:[1,1],[2,2][1,1,1] and so on
why it is returning [ ]?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the usage of the nums.index function. The way it is implemented, it returns the first index of a list where the argument equals the element in the list (as can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)). So, on each iteration of this loop with the input [3, 3], the nums.index(i) and nums.index(j) calls always return 0 (because the 0th index of the input contains 3, which is the value of i and j on each iteration). So, the check fails on every iteration and nothing is returned. In my reproduction of your problem my function returned None instead of []. Perhaps with your type annotations None is interpreted to be [].

A different approach to avoid this issue may include iterating over the indices of the input as opposed to the values.